# load master page once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a template based website where my background is common for all the html pages. Is there any particular solution that loads my background image only once and use the same for my remaining html files?

Comment: Browser love to cache image

Comment: Simply make sure you use the same image on all pages and browsers will cache it after loading only once. Sometimes a user can disable caching or hit Ctrl-F5 which prevents cached versions from being used. Also note that if you change your image, it will not change for all users instantly, some users will have it cached.

Comment: it will takelong time to load the page on each click

Comment: here's something about caching: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/ so the image (and content) will be stored on the users computer and doesn't need to download it from your server everytime

Comment: what i did for my small website was just have all things in a single page and slideUp and slideDown particular divs on clicking some links type looking buttons., this just looked like changing a page. but actually nothing was loaded any time other than once when the website was opened.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting way to cache your images across HTML pages is to add your images as **data URI** inside CSS.

Use this CSS class across the HTML pages and browsers do love to cache the CSS files too ;)

[Read this and decide what's best for you!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469604/using-an-image-file-vs-data-uri-in-the-css)

Tip: Try to make a small .png image file and do a [{background-repeat: repeat}](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) in css

Answer (score 0):

You could create an external css (style sheet) with the below code, and then link that style sheet to all of your pages.  Then the body tag of each page would have the image as it's background.

```
body
{
    background-image:url('some-pic.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

**note:**  The *background-repeat* attribute tells how the image will be repeated as follows:

**repeat-x**:  The background image will be repeated only horizontally
**repeat-y**:  The background image will be repeated only vertically
**no-repeat**:  The background-image will not be repeated
**inherit**:  Specifies that the setting of the background-repeat property should be inherited from the parent element